# Trouble with GeoServer SLD Script - Point Layer Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: geoserver, wms, sld

I'm facing an issue with GeoServer where a layer does not display correctly despite configuring a Styled Layer Descriptor (SLD) script to style the features based on attribute values. I've carefully checked the SLD script and ensured that the filter logic is correctly selecting features based on attribute values.

Additionally, I've taken the following steps to troubleshoot the issue:

Confirmed that the layer configuration in GeoServer is accurate and pointing to the correct data source. All Ids are in the View
Checked the GeoServer log files for any errors or warnings, but found none.
Verified that the data source is properly configured and that the attribute values in the data match the expected values.
Validated the SLD script to ensure there are no syntax errors or other issues.
when the Layer victor layer is connected to a generic style it works well
when i delete the big part of the style and juts let the first part it works
Despite these efforts, the layer still does not display as expected in the GeoServer preview.
i have geoserver 2.23.0 and a PostGIS Database.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
    xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd">
    <NamedLayer>
        <Name>Punkt Stil</Name>
        <UserStyle>
            <Title>Point style</Title>
            <FeatureTypeStyle>
                <!-- L Gelb -->
                <Rule>
                    <Title>P</Title>
                     <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>1</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName> <!-- Dreieck -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>20</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>Psds</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis groß -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>19</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PSdsds</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>3</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis klein -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>15</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS3</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>4</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis groß mit dicken Strich -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter> <!-- schwarz -->
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter> <!-- Strichstärke 2 -->
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>17</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS4 (entspr. GVPV)</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>diamond</WellKnownName> <!-- Raute -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>17</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
              <Rule>
                    <Title>GVPV Gleisvermarkung</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>6</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>diamond</WellKnownName> <!-- Raute -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#FFD700</CssParameter> <!-- gelb -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>14</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <!-- Lsys Lila -->
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS0</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>11</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>triangle</WellKnownName> <!-- Dreieck -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>20</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS1</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis groß -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>19</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS2</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>13</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis klein -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>15</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS3</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>14</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>circle</WellKnownName> <!-- Kreis groß mit dicken Strich -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                                <Stroke>
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter> <!-- schwarz -->
                                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">2</CssParameter> <!-- Strichstärke 2 -->
                                </Stroke>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>17</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <Rule>
                    <Title>PS4 (entspr. GVPV)</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>15</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>diamond</WellKnownName> <!-- Raute -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>17</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
                <!-- GVPV Gleisvermarkung -->
                <Rule>
                    <Title>GVPV Gleisvermarkung</Title>
                    <ogc:Filter>
                        <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>visu</ogc:PropertyName>
                            <ogc:Literal>16</ogc:Literal>
                        </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                    </ogc:Filter>
                    <PointSymbolizer>
                        <Graphic>
                            <Mark>
                                <WellKnownName>diamond</WellKnownName> <!-- Raute -->
                                <Fill>
                                    <CssParameter name="fill">#9400D3</CssParameter> <!-- lila -->
                                </Fill>
                            </Mark>
                            <Size>14</Size>
                        </Graphic>
                    </PointSymbolizer>
                </Rule>
            </FeatureTypeStyle>
        </UserStyle>
    </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: What does display? Can you add small steps to a working SLD and see when it stops working

Comment: I'm not sure diamond is a well-known name

Comment: Adding to Ian's comment (he is correct) - https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/pointsymbols.html#standard-symbols